# local host and port number in Server variable

Tags: php

I have the following snippet that I am stuck at how to figure out getting the port number so the result might "turn" out correct as expected.

```
$server_list = array(       
        "localhost:8282" => array("test" => FALSE, "site_id" => "flyToHeaven"),
);

$server_name = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
if (!isset($server_list[$server_name])) {
    $server_name = "unknown";
    print "unknown server name!!";
    exit();
```

i will always get "Unknown Server Name" in the output. If I delete the port number after localhost then the error is different, which means it passed this 'if' condition. Any help please ....

Comment: Try echoing `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` to see what it contains...

Comment: It displays localhost only, and there for the If performs a mismatch comparison

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is a combination of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']`, which defaults to port 80.

Try this:

```
$server_name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 2):

I am using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` which gives me server-name::port-number. The documentation says that this is "contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one".

My runtime environment is apache running on Linux and PHP 5.4 and this has always worked.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` will only return the name of the server.

If you're typing in `http://localhost:8282` in the browser,

you'll get `'localhost'` as the value of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.

If you want to get the request port, you want to use `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']`. If you combine them both like so:

```
$server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
```

then you will get something closer to what you want.

I would suggest you look at the $_SERVER [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for all the details.